# Difficult Integral: $\int\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate this difficult integral: $\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$?

The answer is $\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^2\pm{a^2}}\mp\frac{a^2}{2}\log(x+\sqrt{x^2\pm{a^2}})$.

And how about $\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$?

Comment: WA now seems to understand LaTeX and so it is easy to experiment and see a general form. Try http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E3%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B1%2Bx%5E2%7D%7Ddx and change the exponent.

Comment: Where did $a$ come from?

Comment: There is a nice recursion you can derive: letting $\mu_n=\int \frac{t^n}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\mathrm dt$, we have $$\mu_n=\frac1{n}(t^{n-1}\sqrt{1+t^2}-(n-1)\mu_{n-2})$$. The integrals for $n=0,1$ are easily derived, so you can use those to start the recursion.

Comment: but how did you get this recursion？

Answer (score 19):

Recall the hyperbolic functions 
$$\cosh t= \frac{e^t + e^{-t}}{2} = \cos(it)$$ 
and $$\sinh t=\frac{e^t - e^{-t}}{2} = i\sin(-it).$$

Note that $\frac{d}{dt}\sinh t = \cosh t$, $\frac{d}{dt}\cosh t = \sinh t$ and also $\cosh^2 t -\sinh^2 t = 1$.

Making the substitution $\sinh t=x $ we see that
$$\frac{x^n\, dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \frac{\sinh^n t\, \cosh t\,dt}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2t}}=
\frac{\sinh^n t\, \cosh t\,dt}{\sqrt{\cosh^2t}}=\sinh^n t\, dt$$
which leads us to $$\int\frac{x^n\, dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \int \sinh^n t\, dt.$$
To complete the problem, the binomial theorem is useful.

Comment: This is one case where the hyperbolic sine is a better substitution choice than the tangent.

Comment: @J.M.: It is fairly standard in the hyperbolic world :)

Comment: @J. M.: The integration is definitely easier with $x=\sinh(t)$, but it often leaves a more involved back-substitution to get things in terms of $x$.

Comment: @robjohn: Dunno, but I don't find $\mathrm{arsinh}(x)$ complicated...

Comment: @robjohn: That is why we get the $\log$ etc.

Comment: I guess the difference is between $$\int\frac{x^6\;\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac{1}{48}((8x^5-10x^3+15x)\sqrt{1+x^2}-15\log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}))+C$$ and $$\int\frac{x^6\;\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac{1}{32}(\cosh(6\operatorname{asinh}(x))-6\cosh(4\operatorname{asinh}(x))+15\cosh(2\operatorname{asinh}(x)))+C$$

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way to go about deriving a recursion relation for integrals of the form

$$\int\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx$$

Split the integral like so:

$$\int x^{n-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx$$

and integrate by parts:

$$\int x^{n-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx=x^{n-1}\sqrt{1+x^2}-(n-1)\int\sqrt{1+x^2} x^{n-2}\mathrm dx$$

Noting that $1+x^2$ is always positive for real $x$, we then complicate things a little:

$$\int \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx=x^{n-1}\sqrt{1+x^2}-(n-1)\int(1+x^2)\frac{x^{n-2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx$$

Perform another split:

$$\int\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx=x^{n-1}\sqrt{1+x^2}-(n-1)\left(\int \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx+\int\frac{x^{n-2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx\right)$$

and we see something we can isolate:

$$n\int\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx=x^{n-1}\sqrt{1+x^2}-(n-1)\int\frac{x^{n-2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx$$

and then we finally divide both sides by $n$:

$$\int\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx=\frac1{n}\left(x^{n-1}\sqrt{1+x^2}-(n-1)\int\frac{x^{n-2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx\right)$$

We can use the starting values $\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\mathrm{arsinh}\,x$ and $\int\frac{x \mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ for the recursion.

(This is a response to Srivatsan's comment, which got too long for the comment box.)

Comment: Thanks for writing the answer. (Btw I ran out of votes, so I'll upvote it when I get them back.)

Comment: @Sri: No worries; I expend my votes too quickly, too.

Answer (score 6):

I would first try the substitution $x=\tan(\theta)$, so that $\sqrt{1+x^2}=\sec(\theta)$. That gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\;\mathrm{d}x
&=\int \tan^n(\theta)\sec(\theta)\;\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\tan^{n-1}(\theta)\sec(\theta)-(n-1)\int\tan^{n-2}(\theta)\;\sec^3(\theta)\;\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\tan^{n-1}(\theta)\sec(\theta)-(n-1)\int(\tan^n(\theta)+\tan^{n-2}(\theta))\;\sec(\theta)\;\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\tan^{n-1}(\theta)\sec(\theta)-\frac{n-1}{n}\int\tan^{n-2}(\theta)\;\sec(\theta)\;\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align}
$$
If $n$ is odd, this reduces to
$$
\int\tan(\theta)\sec(\theta)\;\mathrm{d}\theta=\sec(\theta)+C
$$
If $n$ is even, this reduces to 
$$
\begin{align}
\int\sec(\theta)\;\mathrm{d}\theta&=\int\sec^2(\theta)\;\mathrm{d}\sin(\theta)\\
&=\int\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-\sin(\theta)}+\frac{1}{1+\sin(\theta)}\right)\;\mathrm{d}\sin(\theta)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+\sin(\theta)}{1-\sin(\theta)}\right)+C\\
&=\log(\sec(\theta)+\tan(\theta))+C
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{1+t^2} = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$, we can integrate by parts to get
$$
\int \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\mathrm dt = \int t\cdot \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\mathrm dt
= t\sqrt{1+t^2} - \int \sqrt{1+t^2}\mathrm dt.
$$
Cheating a little bit by looking at a table of integrals, we get that since
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left [ t\sqrt{1+t^2} + \ln(t + \sqrt{1+t^2}) \right ]
= t\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} + \sqrt{1+t^2} + \frac{1}{t + \sqrt{1+t^2}}
\left [ 1 + \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} \right ]
$$
which simplifies to $2\sqrt{1+t^2}$, the integral on the right above is 
$\frac{1}{2}[t\sqrt{1+t^2} + \ln(t + \sqrt{1+t^2})]$ and thus we have
$$
\int \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\mathrm dt 
= \frac{1}{2}\left [t\sqrt{1+t^2} - \ln(t + \sqrt{1+t^2})\right ] 
$$
which matches the answer given by Charles Bao if we set $X=x$ and $a=1$ in his original post.