# Shortcuts for integrating $\int \sqrt{x^2-36} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Is there any simple method to solve this integral

> $$\int \sqrt{x^2-36} \,dx$$

Because my method is a bit complicated and long: [image]

Comment: Could you rotate your picture and make it bigger?

Comment: This is roughly as clean as one can expect---like you observe the integral $\int \sec u \tan^2 u \,du$ is more or less the same difficulty as $\int \sec^3 u \,du$ (the integrands differ by $\sec u$, which can be handled by a reduction formula, but this formula is roughly as easy to produce as the antiderivative of $\sec^3 u$ itself; this calculation is tricky enough to warrant its own Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed .

Comment: Friend said that it can be solved by hyperbolic function. But I don't know

Comment: @Travis Do you know hyperbolic function ?

Comment: @user219126 Yes, you can also substitute $$x = 6 \cosh t$$ to exploit the identity $$\cosh^2 t = \sinh^2 t + 1.$$ This is indeed shorter provided you're familiar with hyperbolic functions and some of their identities and inverses, but typically students learning about trigonometric substitution for the first time haven't encountered them yet. They're anyway worth knowing about, and I encourage you to work out the problem using that kind of a substitution too, since you seem to have mastered at least the aspects of trigonometric substitution needed for this kind of problem.

Comment: Yet another option (also usually not encountered in a first calculus class, but still elementary) is the so-called Euler substitution, which transforms certain expressions involving square roots of quadratics into rational ones: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution In this case, substitute $\sqrt{x^2 - 36} = x + t$.

Comment: I've now given a few partial answers in these comments, so I collected them (and said a bit more) in an answer below.

Comment: @Travis Can you show for the Euler substitution?

Comment: @user219126 Sure, I've expanded the discussion of both the hyperbolic and Euler substitution techniques in my answer; in particular, for the latter I show how to produce an explicit rational integrand in the new variable $t$.

Answer (score 2):

If one restricts to using trigonometric substitution, this is roughly as clean as one can expect: Like you observe the integral $\int \sec u \tan^2 u \,du$ is more or less the same difficulty as evaluation $\int \sec^3 u \,du$ (the integrands differ by $\sec u$, which is standard); this calculation is tricky enough to warrant its own [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed).

There are at least two other techniques available.

**Hyperbolic substitution** Like OP pointed out in the comments, it's possible to evaluate the integral with a hyperbolic substitution. The identity $\cosh^2 u = \sinh^2 u + 1$ suggests the substitution
$$x = 6 \cosh u, \qquad dx = 6 \sinh u \,du,$$
which transforms the integral to the simple-looking
$$\int \sinh^2 u \,du.$$
In close analogy with the corresponding trigonometric integral, we can evaluate this in turn using the ''double-angle identity''
$$\cosh 2u = 2 \sinh^2 u + 1,$$
giving
$$\int \sinh^2 u \, du = \frac{1}{2} \int (\cosh 2u - 1) \,du = \frac{1}{4} \sinh 2u - \frac{u}{2} + C.$$
With this technique the more demanding aspects of this integration are shunted into computing the antiderivative in terms of the original variable $x$; the expressions involving logarithms and radicals arise from the explicit formulas for the applicable inverse hyperbolic function.

**The Euler Substitution** Finally, we can use the so-called [Euler Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution), which transforms certain integrands involving a square root of a quadratic expression into a rational integrand. In this case, the appropriate substitution is $$\sqrt{x^2 - 36} = x + t.$$ Rearranging gives
$$x = - \frac{t}{2} - \frac{18}{t} \, \qquad dx = \left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{18}{t^2}\right) dt,$$
so
$$\sqrt{x^2 - 36} = x + t = \frac{t}{2} - \frac{18}{t}$$
and hence
$$\int \sqrt{x^2 - 36} \,dx = \int \left(\frac{t}{2} - \frac{18}{t}\right) \left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{18}{t^2}\right) dt .$$
But this integrand in $t$ is rational; in fact, after distributing it is a sum of power functions and hence particularly easy to integrate. Reversing the substitution to write the antiderivative is $x$ is somewhat tedious but routine.

Comment: By trig substitution the solution isn't very short in my opinion. Euler substitutions are interesting, although I don't think anyone actually remembers them!

Comment: No, it's certainly not short, but if one insists on using trig substitution, I don't think one can improve too much on OP's method, since any work one does will be tantamount to integrating $\sec^3 u$, which is itself involved.

Comment: @Travis how to solve by Euler substitution ?

Comment: I've expanded my answer some, please see above.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Make the change of variable $x=6\cosh u$. Then

$$\int \sqrt{x^2-36} \,dx=36\int \sinh^2u\,du=18\int(\cosh 2u-1)\,du=9\sinh2u-18u+C\\=\frac x2\sqrt{x^2-36}-18\text{ arcosh }\frac x6+C.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think integration by parts is the shortest way here. Let $u = \sqrt{x^2 - 36}$ and $\mathrm dv = \mathrm dx$. Then,
$$\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{x^2 - 36}\,\mathrm dx &= x\sqrt{x^2 - 36} - \int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 - 36}}\,\mathrm dx =\\[0.3em]
&= x\sqrt{x^2 - 36} - \int\frac{x^2 - 36 + 36}{\sqrt{x^2 - 36}}\,\mathrm dx =\\[0.3em]
&= x\sqrt{x^2 - 36} - \color{green}{\int\sqrt{x^2 - 36}\,\mathrm dx} - 36\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2 - 36}}\,\mathrm dx=\\[0.3em]
&= \frac x2\sqrt{x^2 - 36} - 18\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2 - 36}}\,\mathrm dx =\tag{$\star$}\\[0.5em]
&= \frac x2\sqrt{x^2 - 36} - 18\operatorname{arccosh}\frac x6 + C'
\end{align}$$

In step $(\star)$ we moved the highlighted term to the LHS and divided by $2$. Then we used the fact that
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\operatorname{arccosh} x = \frac1{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}.$$

You can also rewrite the result in another form, using $\operatorname{arccosh} x$ definition:
$$\operatorname{arccosh} x = \ln\left(x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1}\right);$$
in this case, we can write
$$\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{x^2 - 36}\,\mathrm dx &= \frac x2\sqrt{x^2 - 36} - 18\ln\left(\frac x6 + \frac16\sqrt{x^2 - 36}\right) + C' =\\[0.3em]
&= \boxed{\displaystyle\frac x2\sqrt{x^2 - 36} - 18\ln\left(x + \sqrt{x^2 - 36}\right) + C}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

If we put $x = \sqrt{t^2+36}$, then $dx = \frac{2t}{\sqrt{t^2+36}}\,dt$ and
$$\int\sqrt{x^2-36}\,dx= \int \frac{2t^2}{\sqrt{t^2+36}}\,dt$$
which leads back to [Difficult Integral: $\int\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/difficult-integral-int-fracxn-sqrt1x2dx/64466#64466)