# Find the arc-distance between the start and end points of a Bézier curve

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

Given that I have the start, end and control points for a linear Bézier curve, I am trying to find the arc-distance between the start and end points. Google seems to be failing me this morning; can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you have a parametric curve $\begin{align*}x&=f(t)\\y&=g(t)\end{align*}$ for $a \leq t \leq b$, then the arclength you want is $\int_a^b \sqrt{f^\prime(t)^2+g^\prime(t)^2}\mathrm dt$.

Comment: For the non-linear case, possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/arc-length-of-bezier-curves

Answer (score 2):

A linear  Bézier curve is just a straight line segment and so the answer is given by the Pythagorean theorem. For non-linear curves, see [Arc Length of Bézier Curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/arc-length-of-bezier-curves).