# Calculating the length of a NURBS curve

Tags: geometry, 3d

I'm attempting to find the length of a NURBS curve, but I'm not having any luck (I'm also not entirely sure if NURBS are more of a programming thing, I initially asked this question over on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246369/length-of-nurbs-line) then realised it was probably more appropriate here, I hope it's okay to post it again on another stack exchange?).

I have a NURBS line which is always composed of 3 points, 3 weights, the knot vector, and is of degree 2.

It doesn't have to be 100% accurate, converting into a polyline and working out the combined length of the segments would be fine too.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to approach this?

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330232/approximate-arc-length-of-cubic-bezier-curve and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/arc-length-of-bézier-curves.

Comment: huh, seems like searching for NURBS instead of Bezier Curve was my problem. Those links look promising, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not quite sure how to approach this. The solutions I've found don't seem to take into account weighted control points.