# Resample Bézier Curve with curvature and number of points constraints

Tags: geometry, algebraic-curves, curvature, bezier-curve

I have an algorithm that implements an uniform resample process throughout a Bézier curve. This is done using a chord parametrization process.

However, the results achieved do not accomplish my needs. I have noticed a lack in the algorithm: regions of high curvature are simpler, with less information (samples), and does not represent the original curve with precision.

What I actually need is an algorithm to resample the Bézier curve such that more samples are located in regions with high curvature. But other constraint must me respected: I need a specific number of points in the resampled curve.

Any suggestion?

Thank in advance!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/61796/589.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the curve to be resampled is itself a piece-wise (cubic) bezier curve.  Then a variation of the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas-Peucker_algorithm) algorithm may do what you want. The algorithm as described in the link can be generalized because of the following facts:

1. The extremal values of a projection of a bezier curve can easily be found (at least for quadratic and cubic curves).
2. A Bezier curve can be split at any point into two shorter bezier curves.

The stopping criterium for resampling can be a combination of number of resample points and maximal allowed error.