# How did length of base polyline relate with length of Bézier curve?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, bezier-curve

Let cubic Bézier curve $C$ be based on points $p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3$. Suppose $L$ is the polyline through $p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3$. Is there some well known analytical relation between lengths of these two geometrical objects?

Comment: I am almost sure that there is no equation linking the one to the other. Maybe an inequation ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, I suppose that there is some relation. To check this I want to find relation of lengths of these objects. Unfortunately some additional work is needed (for example to find integral etc.)

Comment: For the length of a Bezier curve, have you seen (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/12186), with many references in it ?

Comment: Two questions: 1) Why don't you begin by a quadratic Bezier curve (i.e., an arc of parabola). Cubic Bezier curve are more complicated... 2) In your question, you say "a" polyline, why not "the" polyline ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, good mention. I did not see this post before. I prefer work with cubic bezier curves because it is the most popular type of bezier curve in computational geometry. I agree with your second question. I suppose that usage of "the" is preferable

Comment: Well, the closed-form arclength expression for a cubic Bézier is not terribly practical for you (it needs elliptic integrals), while getting the arclength of a polyline only needs judicious use of the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: I don't think you can find a relation between the two lengths. Take, as an example, two segments with a common vertex and the quadratic Bezier curve generated. If you open the angle between the two segments, the polyline will still have the same length, though the quadratic curve will be stretched and its length supposedly varies.
So probably, that would also depend on the angles and not only on the length of the polyline.

Comment: Btw, I've just found this that may help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/arc-length-of-b%C3%A9zier-curves

Comment: Yes, I agree this post clarifies answer. Note that it has showed earlier by JeanMarie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This paper has some material that might be relevant:

> [Specifying the arc length of Bézier curves](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0167-8396(93)90050-D)
>   John A. Roulier
>   Computer Aided Geometric Design
>   Volume 10, Issue 1, February 1993, Pages 25-56

For example he shows that the length of the curve is less than the length of the polyline. The proof is fairly simple.