# What should be minimized in order to best approximate a curve?

Tags: optimization, approximation, algebraic-curves, curves, curvature

I have a smooth parametrized curve $r(t), t \in [0,1]$ in the plane and I want to find a sequence $r(t_1), r(t_2), ... r(t_n)$ which "best" approximates the curve. I'd like to know how to define "best".

Intuitively, I expect that the points should be more densely distributed in sections of the curve with high curvature. For example, I expect that samples of a parabola will be denser near its intersection with the line of symmetry. In the extreme case of a straight line, I expect the points to be uniformly distributed on the curve.

I suspect that there is some function F of r and the n points that is minimized/maximined at the "optimal" distribution of points. Ideally, there should be a simple algorithm for calculating these points from such a function.

Consider, for example, $F = \sum_i \kappa_i$ where $\kappa_i$ is the curvature at $r(t_i)$. It seems reasonable to want to choose $t_1, ..., t_n$ that maximize $F$, but I imagine that there is a less ad hoc choice of $F$ ... one that suggests a natural algorithm for selecting $t_1, ..., t_n$.

As a concrete example, find an algorithm for sampling n points on the parabola described parametrically by: $r(t) = (t, t^2), 0\leq t \leq 1$.

Any ideas? References?

Comment: For a Bézier curve, simply picking equally spaced $t$ values will work.

Comment: You can check "Numerical Recipes" which have a long discussion about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

A classic method is the [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm). You start with a densely sampled polyline, and recursively decide whether to keep or discard vertices based on how much approximation error discarding would introduce.

Answer (score 1):

This paper discusses the problem:

- H. Imai and M. Iri. Polygonal approximations of a curve-formulations and algorithms. In G. T. Toussaint, editor, *Computational Morphology*, pages 71—86. North- Holland, 1988.

This paper seems interesting:

- P.L. Rosin, ["Techniques for assessing polygonal approximations of curves"](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Paul.Rosin/pami-assessment.pdf), *IEEE Transactions Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence*, vol. 19, no. 6, pp. 659—666, 1997. DOI: 10.1109/34.601253

For a recent paper, see

- Pankaj K. Agarwal, Sariel Har-Peled, Nabil H. Mustafa, and Yusu Wang. 2002. Near-Linear Time Approximation Algorithms for Curve Simplification. In Proceedings of the 10th Annual European Symposium on Algorithms (ESA '02), Springer-Verlag, pp. 29—41.

Adaptive arc-length computation is a good proxy for curvature-adaptive approximation. In this context, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61796/589).

Answer (score 0):

These are good comments and references, but I think that the method that most closely answers the call is http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~tess/publications/curve_sampling.pdf.

Thanks!